# neo4j, in a forum structure, how to find how many response each post got (including child of child...)

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm writing a program that analyse posts in a forum.
After loading forum threads into **neo4j DB**,
I'm trying to **"Rank" posts** by the **number of responses** they got.

**Responses** include direct responses as well as the entire sub-tree for each direct response.
The idea is to count all children down the tree (the tree is a simple tree **without any loops**)

Every post is a **neo4j node**

> ```
> # Create MSG nodes:
> statement = "CREATE (c:MSG {id:{N}, title:{T}}) RETURN c"
> for msg in msgs:
>     graph.cypher.execute(statement, {"N": msg[0], "T": msg[1]})
> ```

Node that represent a post which is a response to another post has a relation **r:CHILD_OF** to his parent node.
root nodes will not have r:CHILD_OF relation, but will have a "0" as their parent ID

```
|parent id | msg id | Rank | List of all responses
+----------+--------+------+----------------------
|0         | 1051   | 3    | (1054, 1056, 1060)
|1051      | 1054   | 0    |
|1051      | 1056   | 1    | (1060)
|1056      | 1060   | 0    |
|0         | 1052   | 0    |
```

in this table,

- msg 1051 is a first post in a thread
- msg 1052 is a first post in another thread
- msg 1051 got 2 direct responses (1054, 1056) and another in-direct response (1060)
- msg 1056 got 1 direct response (1060)

**I need to get the cypher that can create this ranking**.
But not sure how to write it.
The project is in python and I'm using python 2.7, py2neo 2.0.3, neo4j 2.1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should return a result set similar to your table (but without the first column):

```
MATCH (m:MSG)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:MSG)-[:CHILD_OF*1..]->(m)
WITH m, COLLECT(DISTINCT c.id) AS childMsgIds
RETURN m.id AS `msg id`, LENGTH(childMsgIds) AS Rank, childMsgIds AS `List of all responses`
```

Does this suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

This should return all distinct children in the tree:

```
MATCH (message:MSG {id: {message_id}})<-[:CHILD_OF*0..]-(child:MSG)
RETURN DISTINCT child
```

If you want a count, you can do `RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT child)`

Comment: Thanks, I up voted this answer because it is in the right direction. Two minor issues: You have to count from 1 and not from 0, and this will return answer for specific node only.

Comment: Ah, good point about the 0/1.  I put in the `id` though because that seems to have been what you wanted from your question.